# Making an enemy bounce off the walls (Javascript/Jquery)

Tags: jquery, animation, random

I am trying to make a game for school, the game is simple.
1. player needs to eat cakes to score points
2. a fixed number of enemies spawn randomly and move randomly
3. enemies have to bounce off of walls and move to another random direction

My issue here is: I made a for-loop creating a few enemies, these enemies move and spawn randomly, but don't bounce off the walls. These enemies get their ID from the for-loop (#enemy + i) and I push them into an array.

I know I have to use setInterval in order to make it check each time if an enemy is at the border, but I can't seem to make it work.

```
In order to make the code easier to understand:
randomTopVijand = creates a random top position for each enemy
randomLeftVijand = creates a random left position for each enemy
randomRichting = decides in which direction the enemy will go
```

At first I tried to make the animation stop at the walls, but that didn't work out.
Would highly appreciate if someone could help me making those guys bounce of the walls.

```
function maakVijand() {

    for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++) {

        randomTopVijand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 580);
        randomLeftVijand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 780);
        randomRichting = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);

        $("#terrain").append("<img src='IMG/knight_sprite.gif' id='enemy" + i + "' />");
        arrayVijand.push("enemy" + i);
        $("#enemy" + i).css({
            position : "absolute",
            top : randomTopVijand + "px",
            left : randomLeftVijand + "px"
        });

        if (randomRichting == 0) {

            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                'left' : '-=200',
                'top' : '-=200'
            }, 1750);
        } else if (randomRichting == 1) {
            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                'top' : '-=610'
            }, 1750);
        } else if (randomRichting == 2) {
            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                'left' : '+=810',
                'top' : '-=610'
            }, 1750);
        } else if (randomRichting == 3) {
            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                'left' : '+=810'
            }, 1750);
        } else if (randomRichting == 4) {
            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                'left' : '+=810',
                'top' : '+=610'
            }, 1750);
        } else if (randomRichting == 5) {
            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                'top' : '+=610'
            }, 1750);
        } else if (randomRichting == 6) {
            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                left : '-=810',
                top : '+=610'
            }, 1750);
        } else if (randomRichting == 7) {
            $("#enemy" + i).animate({
                left : '-=810'
            }, 1750);
        }

        if ($("#enemy" + i).position.top <= positiescherm.left) {
            $("#enemy" + i).stop(true, false);
        }
        if ($('#enemy' + i).position().left <= positiescherm.left) {
            $('#enemy' + i).stop(true, false);
        } else if ($("#enemy" + i).position().left + $("#enemy" + i).width() >= positiescherm.right) {
            $("#enemy" + i).stop(true, false);
        } else if ($("#enemy" + i).position().top <= positiescherm.top) {
            $("#enemy" + i).stop(true, false);
        } else if ($("#enemy" + i).position().top + $("#enemy" + i).height >= positiescherm.bottom) {
            $("#enemy" + i).stop(true, false);
        }
    }
}
```